# Translating HTML5 Form Helpers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I am using the `date_field_tag`.

```
<%= date_field_tag :date_from, value = nil, options = {} %>
```

The date picker is displayed in English, with the machine locale set to is.I am wondering if it is possible to translate the date picker text using `I18n.t`? Or is this not possible since the date picker is provided by the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails helper `date_field_tag` [generates an input field with a type of "date"](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/date_field_tag), but [it's not a widely supported  field type](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime). You can either let the browser render the field and hope for the best, or use a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) to provide support for users who don't have a browser with the functionality. You could also use something like [the jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for everybody, regardless of whether the browser supports date fields or not.

Your options for translating the control depend on which approach you take. If the browser is drawing the calendar widget, you can't control the language it uses. If you're providing a calendar widget via JavaScript, then you can - it's just HTML, after all. jQuery's datepicker provides [a lot of localisation options](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

You can try out how your browser displays native date-related fields [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bgd36x7/).

Comment: Thank you for a very clear and informative answer.
I will need to read up on jQuery's datepicker.